What is the expanded form of "éd. augm."?
What is the uncontracted form of éd. augm.?
Consider the following snippet of text:

« Ludis » (par C. du Cange, 1678), dans du Cange, et al., Glossarium mediae et infimae latinitatis, éd. augm., Niort : L. Favre, 1883‑1887, t. 5, col. 149a. http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/LUDIS


As already mentioned in a comment, the answer is édition augmentée: “expanded edition”.

I can't find a difference between augmented edition and expanded edition.  In English outside of reference citations, "expanded" seems more familiar to to me.  J'ai loupé les commentaires me semble-t-il ; is there a difference you find between expanded and augmented in citation styles?

Your source is a Latin glossary, a composite work of the medieval and modern over two centuries.
The contents of the first publication were augmented in the 1730s by the Benedictine order in the church of Saint Maur.  More editors contributed until the late 1880s.  From the section Who? Authors and Editor History Qui ? — Auteurs et histoire éditoriale. :

(1733-1736), les Bénédictins de la congrégation de Saint-Maur
augmentent le contenu, en s’insérant dans le plan initial.

The notation ed. augm. is also found in an English language style guide for abbreviations despite my  searching in French. It is however a medical style guide not like your source, which is itself a Latin glossary dated 1883-87.  Both abbreviations come from the Latin.
Citing Medicine: The NLM Style Guide for Authors, Editors, and Publishers.
edition ed.
abbreviated abbr.
abridged    abr.
American    Am.
augmented   augm.
authorized  authoriz.
English Engl.
enlarged    enl.
expanded    expand.

It gives separate entries for augm. (augmented) and expand. (expanded). That may have to do with the medical definition of augmentation in some contexts, but for the purposes of citations, I expect the difference is far more nuanced than I understand other than agency, that one has been augmented by an editor and one is an expanded edition. Bigger on the inside.
(It is unclear to me where this question is best suited because these are Latin based international abbreviations that do apply to common style guides and reference materials about across several languages. It is clearly derived from augmento, augmentare, first conjugation in Latin, though your source is in French.)

@cmw D'ac et tout a fait d'accord avec la révision donc moi aussi je révise afin de l'ignorer.  Sinon la glossaire est super intéressante à lire sans blague, lèche vitrine là j'en ai envie !

If you're a dictionary reader too, look out, it's a fun one.  I agree with your edit and revised accordingly.  It makes me want the Latin tag for good traffic but it's yield friendly.
